# Stripe Product metadata not returning to Firebase's authenticated user instance when using Run Payments with Stripe Firebase Extension

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, stripe-payments

I'm using the [Run Payments with Stripe Firebase Extension](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/stripe-firestore-stripe-payments).

I set a metadata field in the Stripe Product of: `userRole: premium`.

The webhook returns `userRole: premium` in Firestore under `Users` >> `subscriptions` >> `metadata.userRole`.

But I expected the webhook to attach `userRole` to Firebase's `auth.currentUser` instance. Which I was planning to query for using the function below.

How can I make the webhook return this metadata to `auth.currentUser`?

```
import { auth } from '../src/utils/init-firebase';

export default async function isUserPremium() {
    await auth.currentUser?.getIdToken(true);

    const decodedToken = await auth.currentUser?.getIdTokenResult();
    console.log(decodedToken);

    return decodedToken?.claims?.userRole ? true : false;
    // return decodedToken?.claims?.stripeRole ? true : false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had changed the metadata name to `userRole`.

It must be `firebaseRole` for users to get assigned a custom claim role to give them access to certain data when subscribed to a specific product.

Comment: Hi could you put a screenshot of your metadata from your stripe interface pls ? I face the same problem... it use to works fine but it stop to update my custom claims